# Remove everything before a regex pattern

Tags: regex

I have different data in this format:

ISIN: LU0799639926

I created a regex to filter the important data:

```
\w{2}\d{10}
```

The thing is that I want to delete everything that is before and behind my pattern.
I have already tried

```
[^\w{2}\d{10}]*
```

It selects everything but my pattern, it just doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `.*` subpattern to get anything before and after, capture your substring into a capturing group and then replace with a `$1` backreference:

```
.*(\w{2}\d{10}).*
```

Replace with `$1`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV6fR8/1)

Perhaps, you will be safer with `.*([A-Z]{2}\d{10}).*`, as `\w` may also capture digits, and `[A-Z]` will only match uppercase letters.

If you have multiple values in the input string, perhaps, you will be more interested in getting a delimited string, e.g.:

```
.*?([A-Z]{2}\d{10})
```

To replace with `$1;`.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV6fR8/2)

Comment: If the substring in question is at the beginning of the input string, and there may be multiple values that match your substring, and you only want to keep the first `.*?(\w{2}\d{10}).*` will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
[^\w{2}\d{10}]
```

`{` and `}` are treated as the literals `{` and `}`, they loose their regex meaning.

Try:

```
.*(\w{2}\d{10})
```

This will catch the pattern you want, then you can easily replace it with whatever you want.